# Laravel 5 requested url shows blank page with no error

Tags: laravel-5

I want to show a page when a url is requested but what i get is a blank page despite the fact that the page has content in it. I've been trying to figure what could be wrong with my code but have come up with nothing so far. Here's what i have in my code

In my web.php file, i have this route

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

// Student
Route::get('/students', 'StudController@index');

Route::get('/student/create', 'StudController@create');

Route::post('/students', 'StudController@store');

// Employee
Route::get('/employees', 'EmpController@index');

Route::get('/employee/create', 'EmpController@create');

Route::post('/employees', 'EmpController@store' );

Route::get('/employee/{id}', 'EmpController@show');

// Faculty
Route::get('/faculty', 'FacultyController@index');
```

In the EmpController file, this is the method to show the employee with the id (note the absence of a query as I'm only testing to see if a page is displayed when this uri is requested)

```
public function show()
{
    return view('emp.employee');
}
```

This is the link

```
<a href="/employee/{{ $employee->id }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

This is my employee.blade.php inside the resources/views/emp/ folder

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <h3>Why is this page blank?</h3>
@endsection
```

Error reporting is set to true. What have i missed? This should be simple

Comment: don't you want to catch Id in show  function?

Comment: Check your error log, there has to be some fatal error if it is showing a white page. And make sure you have set your environment to app in .env file

Comment: @ParthVora this the error from the log file **exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING)' in E:\wamp64\www\schoolAdmin\routes\web.php:39** and thses are lines 36 to 39 Route::get('/employee/{id}', 'EmpController@show');

// Faculty
Route::get('/faculty', 'FacultyController@index');

Comment: @Jagrati of course i will be doing that, only testing the route at this point.

Comment: Can you please update the question with full routes/web.php file?

Comment: Are you able to visit other routes successfully? And are you getting that error every time you trying to access that employee/{id} route?

Comment: Other routes work well. Yes, I get the error only when I attempt to visit employee/{id}

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting my system, i was still not able to access the link correctly. Checked laravel.log file and nothing pointed to the issue in it. However i was able to fix this by creating another controller and everything worked perfectly. Still don't know why i had issues though.